# List of dataframe column values

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I am working in a recommendation system program.Given this dataframe,how can I create a list of 30 random tracks based on the values of the intervals columns?

````
track_name     track_artist    liveness    valence     tempo   duration_ms     intervals
 Pangarap    Barbie's Cradle     0.088700    0.566000    97.091000   235440  0
 I Feel Alive    Steady Rollin   0.347000    0.404000    135.225000  373512  -1
 Poison  Bell Biv DeVoe  0.489000    0.650000    111.904000  262467  -1
 Baby    CeeLo Green     0.066400    0.405000    118.593000  243067  -2
 Dumb Litty  KARD    0.138000    0.240000    130.018000  193160  0 ```
````

````
 for i in spotify:
    lista=[]
    if spotify['intervals'].values ==-1:
        lista.append(random(spotify['track_id']['track_name']))
    if spotify['intervals']. ==-2:
        lista.append(random(spotify['track_id']['track_name']))
    if spotify['intervals'].item ==0:
        lista.append(random(spotify['track_id']['track_name']))
    print(lista)
```
````

Whenever I try this code I get this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "depending on the interval" but pandas provide a method `sample`  that extract a random sample of arbitrary size from your dataframe https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html

Comment: If the value of the interval column is -1 return me a list with the track_name values that fits that condition

Comment: What condition is that? I'm also confused. Do you want a random sample of all unique values in the interval column?

Comment: For ex, I feel alive has a value of -1 in the column,i want to have a list of the songs that also has -1 in the intervals column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are comparing an array `spotify['intervals'].values` to a value -1. You need to find if any of them is equal to that value. You can do this -

```
any(spotify['intervals'].values)==-1
```

And so on for all your `elif` conditions

EDIT:
The problem is deeper than the issue you are facing. You are trying to pull n random songs from a group created w.r.t the intervals and then return them. That can be done using a groupby followed by an apply function with random.choice -

```
n = 10 #number of random tracks you need

dd = pd.DataFrame(spotify.groupby(['intervals'])['track_name'].apply(list)).reset_index() #group and get list of songs by intervals

#get n random songs
dd['random_track'] = dd['track_name'].apply(np.random.choice, size=(n,))
dd
```

```
   intervals    track_name              random_track
0   -1          [I Feel Alive, Poison]  Poison
1    0          [Pangarap]              Pangarap
```

The first column is intervals, second is list of all songs there and third is a random song from list.

This should solve your problem. Please read about pandas groupby operations.

Comment: I've done it but now I get this out: ```[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]```

Comment: that has to do with the code that u are running inside the if statement. I have no clue on what is happening inside. Can you describe what u are doing there?

Comment: I want to get a list of the tracks which value in the interval column is in this case -1.For ex,I feel alive and poison have a value of -1 in the intervals column

Comment: why are you using random then?

Comment: To get a random list of the songs

Comment: so you want random song from each interval?

Comment: Yes I want a list with 10 random songs which intervals value is -1,10 random songs which intervals value is -2 and 10 random songs which intervals is 0

Comment: But the only thing i want is the random track as a list not as part of the dataframe

Answer (score 1):

To get a random sample from each value in the interval column you could iterate through each unique value, filter the dataframe and then save to dictionary.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("xxxx.csv")

output = {}

for unique in df["intervals"].unique():
    output[unique] = df[df["intervals"] == unique].sample(30)
```

or create a function that also handles subsets that have a count lower than the required sample size.

```
def get_unique_sample(df, sample_size=30):
    output = {}    
    for unique in df["intervals"].unique():

        subset = df[df["intervals"] == unique]
        samplesize = 30 if len(subset) > 30 else len(subset)
        output[unique] = subset.sample(samplesize )
    return output
```